# How to Remove mouseCallback in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, mouseevent

In OpenCV with C++, Is there a way to remove the

```
mouseHandler(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param) {}
```

added to a window "image_window" by function

```
cv::setMouseCallback("image_window", mouseHandler, (void*)param);
```

Thanks for your advice! :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set the window callback function to `NULL` like this:

```
cv::setMouseCallback("image_window", NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Raised Python Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278574/how-to-remove-mousecallback-in-opencv