# Python: How to Remove mouseCallback in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

With OpenCV and Python, is there any way to remove the mouse callback set with `cv2.setMouseCallback(window_name, function_name)`? Passing `None` for the function name gives;

`TypeError: on_mouse must be callable`

This is a duplicate of [How to Remove mouseCallback in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278574/how-to-remove-mousecallback-in-opencv), but for Python, not C++.

Thanks,

Comment: Why to remove if you havn't set it?

Comment: I have set it, and I'm trying to clean up after my function is called by removing it. Why the downvote?

Comment: Because I don't think this question is useful. `TypeError: on_mouse must be callable` means you have to feed a `functor`, not a `NoneType`. You have `3000+` reputation, I don't think you have really thought your question.

Comment: By the way, an alternative method is to replace with another callback function. Such as `def justpass(*args, **kwargs):pass` and `setMouseCallback(winname, justpass)` when needed.

Comment: Fair call. The empty function approach is what I ended up using. Posted the Q here to see if there was a better way I was missing, and because I figured it might help other people. Thanks.

Comment: Did you get an answer to this question?

Comment: Hi @DrSokoban - just the suggestion above (to replace it with an empty function).

Comment: thanks for your answer @aaronsnoswell it doesnt really works for me, because in the same script I am trying to launch matplotlib, and it fails, I think because opencv with the mousecall is hijacking gdk

Comment: To me this question is absolutely useful.

Answer (score 10):

For me, `cv2.setMouseCallback(window_name, lambda *args : None)` did the trick and it seems clean enough.